# How can I set the content type during itemadding event

Tags: content-type, event-receivers

I am trying to set the content type programmatically using an itemadding eventreceiver so that when the user adds a document to a library the content type is pre-selected. I have two content types: Project Document and Document. I determine through code which type to use and set the column values. My problem is that I can't get the content type to switch to Project Document. Here is my code:

```
   SPContentTypeId ctId = properties.Web.ParentWeb.ContentTypes["Project Document"].Id;
    properties.AfterProperties["Content Type ID"] = ctId;
    properties.AfterProperties["Content Type"] = properties.Web.ParentWeb.ContentTypes[ctId].Name;

    properties.AfterProperties["ProjectID"] = "example id";
    properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = "random document";
    properties.AfterProperties["ProjName"] = "My Project";
    base.ItemAdding(properties);
```

When the properties form opens up the default content type (Document) is showing. When I switch to Project Document the values I added are there.

So my question is: How do I get it to change to the Project Document content type before the properties box opens?

Comment: Can you try SPBuiltInFieldId.ContentTypeId to update content type id. See this as an example http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/01/updating-content-type-of-list-item.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting "ContentType" and "ContentTypeId":

```
properties.AfterProperties["ContentTypeID"] = ctId;
properties.AfterProperties["ContentType"] = properties.Web.ParentWeb.ContentTypes[ctId].Name;
```

Comment: Paul - thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, no matter what I try (ContentTypeID and ContentType or Content Type ID and Content Type) I always end up with the default content type in the dropdown field.

Comment: On second effort(and more careful capitalization), Paul's response was spot on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. By the way, you can set just the ContentType. No need in setting ContentTypeID.